# In Swift 3, how to fix an error about argument labels do not match any available overloads for String type?

Tags: swift, swift3

In Swift 2, I could load data from `somefile.txt` as the code below without problem:

```
let fileManager = FileManager.default
let urls = fileManager.urls(for: .applicationSupportDirectory, in: .userDomainMask)
let appDataURL = urls.last.appendingPathComponent("appData")

let fileDestinationUrl = appDataURL!.appendingPathComponent("somefile.txt")

var dataString = ""
do {
    dataString = try String(contentsOfURL: fileDestinationUrl)  //<-- error here
    print("dataString=\(dataString)")
} catch let error as NSError {
    print("Failed reading data in appData Directory, Error: \(error.localizedDescription)")
}
```

However, in Swift 3, XCode gives an error at line `dataString = try String(contentsOfURL: fileDestinationUrl)` by saying:

```
Argument labels '(contentsOfURL:)' do not match any available overloads
```

How to fix this error? What is the right way to read the text file in Swift 3?

Comment: You can also always just retype `String(` and let XCode show you all the possible initializers and usually you should be able to find out which one to use :)

Comment: I find the autocomplete works maybe 20% of the time. :-/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This method has been updated to (in the context of your example):

```
dataString = try String(contentsOf: fileDestinationUrl)
```

In Swift 3, all function params now have labels unless specifically defined otherwise. This in practice often means the last part of a method name moves to the first params label.